# I have a dual boot desktop running 32 bit Windows 7 and 64 bit linux, with 3 GB RAM I am planning to increase the RAM to 8 GB, is it possible?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, 64-bit, 32-bit

Basic concerns i have are:
1) is it possible
2) will increasing the ram be detrimental to the windows OS ?

I am reluctant to change the windows OS to 64 bit due to licensing hassles.

Comment: I doubt that it will hurt; I expect that the 32-bit Windows OS won’t be able to use all the RAM.

Comment: Windows 32 bit can use a maximum of 4 GB of memory. See [Memory Limits for Windows and Windows Server Releases](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7)

Answer (score 1):

Adding RAM to your system will not affect the 32-bit version of windows 7, it will just use as much as it can!

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but 32-bit Windows will only use the first 4GB of RAM so anything you add beyond that will be wasted.

The only mild detriment you could have to adding RAM is if you add additional RAM which is slower than your current RAM. Having said that, the benefits of the additional RAM will massively outweigh this.

Finally, you don't mention what the licencing hassles are, but you can easily move from 32-bit to 64-bit Windows 7, 8 and 10 with the same licence key. The only downside is that you're going to have to do a fresh install of Windows - but if you're going to get the extra memory then it's absolutely worth the time and effort so you can use it.